# Missing legend for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a subset of lines for my dataset, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the legend to display properly, either normally or using a melt. The dataset has the following structure (more forecasts and dates in actual dataset, this is just an example):

```
Date        Actual Fcst1 Fcst2 Fcst3 Fcst4
2015-01-01  500    600   700   400   450
2015-02-01  600    610   630   480   600
2015-03-01  700    234   875   754   733
..........  ...    ...   ...   ...   ...
```

I am currently using this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fcst1), color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fcst2),
    color = "blue",
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fcst3),
    color = "green",
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fcst4),
    color = "yellow",
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fcst5),
    color = "purple",
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fcst6), color = "orange", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Actual), color = "black", size = 1.2) +
  ggtitle(label = "Actuals vs 2015 Forecasts", subtitle = fname) +
  ylab("Balance") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

I can't get the legend to display properly no matter what, even when I try using a melt. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ggplot2` prefers things in long format, and tends to "punish" (make hard) doing things like you're doing now. Let's reshape (I'll use `tidyr::pivot_longer`, others work just as well).

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, Fcst1:Fcst4),
       aes(Date, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: basic ggplot2]

As you can tell, using `color=` *within* an `aes`thetic varies the colors accordingly. If you want to control the colors, there are many themes available (e.g., `viridis` and many with color-blind profiles), but doing it manually is done with `scale_color_manual`, I'll demo below. Finally, I'll tweak the names and such a little.

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, Actual:Fcst4, names_to = "Forecast", names_prefix = "Fcst"),
       aes(Date, value, color = Forecast)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Actual" = "black", "1" = "red", "2" = "blue",
                                "3" = "green", "4" = "yellow", "5" = "purple",
                                "6" = "orange")) +
  ggtitle(label = "Actuals vs 2015 Forecasts", subtitle = "(unk filename)") +
  ylab("Balance") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

The manual colors don't have to be a perfect match, as you can see with `5` defined but not used (based on your data sample). Missing colors in the `values=` named vector will be removed from the plot (with a warning).

[image: same ggplot2, updated theme]

Finally, a common question is ordering the components in the legend. This can be done with `factor`s:

```r
df_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, Actual:Fcst4, names_to = "Forecast", names_prefix = "Fcst")
df_long$Forecast <- relevel(factor(df_long$Forecast), "Actual")
ggplot(df_long, aes(Date, value, color = Forecast)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Actual" = "black", "1" = "red", "2" = "blue",
                                "3" = "green", "4" = "yellow", "5" = "purple",
                                "6" = "orange")) +
  ggtitle(label = "Actuals vs 2015 Forecasts", subtitle = "(unk filename)") +
  ylab("Balance") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image: same ggplot2, reordered legend]

I used `stats::relevel` to move one factor "to the front", otherwise it tends to be alphabetic (as shown in the second graphic above). There are many tools for working with factors, the `forcats` package is a popular one (esp among tidyverse users).

This processing could easily have been handled within a `dplyr`-pipe.

---

Since you mentioned plotting batches of forecasts at a time, here are a couple of approaches. I'll augment the data by copying the `Fcst` columns into another set of 4:

```r
df <- cbind(df, setNames(df[,3:6], paste0("Fcst", 5:8)))
df_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, Actual:Fcst8, names_to = "Forecast", names_prefix = "Fcst")
df_long$Forecast <- relevel(factor(df_long$Forecast), "Actual")
```

I'll "simplify" the plot for code brevity, though the theming will still work as above.

1. Individual plots, filter one at a time and plot it.

   ```r
   ggplot(df_long[df_long$Forecast %in% c("Actual", "1", "3", "5", "7"),],
          aes(Date, value, color = Forecast)) +
     geom_line(size = 1)
   ```
2. Faceting. I'll show a brute-force way to do this for *this* example, then a more flexible (perhaps) way. I'm using `dplyr` here because it makes several of the operations much easier to see and understand (once you get used to the dplyr-esque syntax). (I often find keeping the control line, "Actual", a different color/thickness than the others help solidify comparisons across the facets. Over to you.)

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   df_rest <- df_long %>%
     filter(! Forecast == "Actual") %>%
     mutate(grp = cut(as.integer(as.character(Forecast)), c(0, 5, 9), labels = FALSE))

   df_combined <- df_long %>%
     filter(Forecast == "Actual") %>%
     select(-grp) %>%
     crossing(., unique(select(df_rest, grp))) %>%
     bind_rows(df_rest)

   ggplot(df_combined, aes(Date, value, color = Forecast)) +
     geom_line(size = 1) +
     facet_grid(grp ~ .)
   ```

   [image: expanded data, ggplot2 faceted]
3. Faceting, but with a more maintainable set of facets. I'll use a simple `data.frame` to control which lines are included in which `$grp`. This makes it much easier (imo) to "cherry pick" specific lines for specific facets.

   ```r
   grps <- tibble::tribble(
     ~grp, ~Forecast
     ,1, "Actual"
     ,1, "1"
     ,1, "3"
     ,1, "5"
     ,2, "Actual"
     ,2, "2"
     ,2, "4"
     ,2, "6"
     ,2, "7"
     ,2, "8"
   )
   ggplot(left_join(df_long, grps, by = "Forecast"),
          aes(Date, value, color = Forecast)) +
     geom_line(size = 1) +
     facet_grid(grp ~ .)
   ```

   In this case, I used `tribble` solely to make it easier to see which goes together; any `data.frame` will work. I also demonstrate that `$grp` sizes do not need to be equal, include whatever you want.
4. Use the frame from #3 above for joining, then just filter on them, as in

   ```r
   left_join(df_long, grps, by = "Forecase") %>%
     filter(grp == 1) %>%
     ggplot(., aes(Date, value, color = Forecast)) +
     geom_line(size = 1) +
     facet_grid(grp ~ .)
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! How would I go about selecting which lines to plot specifically? I have 40 forecasts total, but I am plotting 4 of them plus actuals for the year. For example, for 2015 I want to plot Actuals, Fcst12, Fcst15, Fcst28, and Fcst46. I'm relatively new to ggplot, so I find it kind of frustrating that the legend doesn't show by default the way I did it originally.

Comment: That sounds like a filtering question. If using `dplyr`, then `df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(...) %>% filter(Forecast %in% c("Actual", "12", "15"))`.

Comment: If you aren't comfortable (yet) with `dplyr`, then you can create intermediate (temporary) datasets. This might be done *before* `pivot_longer`, as in `df[,c("Date","Actual","Fcst14","Fcst83")]` and then pivot, or *after* using the `%in%` trick.

Comment: kmai2, I understand your frustration. Please understand that `ggplot2` has many *efficiencies*, and most of them rely on "long data" (vice wide). Brute-forcing it with multiple calls to `geom_line` is relatively inefficient, as it requires you to manually control colors, legends, etc ... and that increases the chances of inconsistencies (i.e., between lines and legends). By making things *inherent* to the data, it reduces or removes that likelihood. If you're more comfortable with base graphics or some non-R plotting library, there is certainly a curve, but please believe me: *it is worth it*.

Comment: @kmai2, see my edit, it provides a couple more options for various groups.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response! I really appreciate all your help! I will try out what you recommend to see if I can figure things out! Also, your last explanation on making things inherent to data makes a lot of sense, and I can understand why they did that. I wish there was a way to have both implemented, but I don't doubt that what you're saying is true. I was just a little confused as a relatively new user. Thanks!